# What's responsible for creating the filename signature in this Gulp task?

Tags: javascript, gulp, bower

When I run `gulp build` it creates a file with a name like this:

```
dist/scripts/app-f3c1dbf348.js
```

The `f3c1dbf348` part is something different every time. Obviously something is making this happen but it's not clear to me what.

Below is my `gulp/build.js`. What there (if anything there) is generating the `f3c1dbf348` part of the filename? I want the filename just to be `app.js` because my concatenated `.js` file needs to be included as a Bower component.

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var conf = require('./conf');

var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
  pattern: ['gulp-*', 'main-bower-files', 'uglify-save-license', 'del']
});

gulp.task('partials', function () {
  return gulp.src([
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.html'),
    path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/app/**/*.html')
  ])
    .pipe($.minifyHtml({
      empty: true,
      spare: true,
      quotes: true
    }))
    .pipe($.angularTemplatecache('templateCacheHtml.js', {
      module: 'lmsComponents',
      root: 'app'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(conf.paths.tmp + '/partials/'));
});

gulp.task('html', ['inject', 'partials'], function () {
  var partialsInjectFile = gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/partials/templateCacheHtml.js'), { read: false });
  var partialsInjectOptions = {
    starttag: '<!-- inject:partials -->',
    ignorePath: path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/partials'),
    addRootSlash: false
  };

  var htmlFilter = $.filter('*.html', { restore: true });
  var jsFilter = $.filter('**/*.js', { restore: true });
  var cssFilter = $.filter('**/*.css', { restore: true });
  var assets;

  return gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/*.html'))
    .pipe($.inject(partialsInjectFile, partialsInjectOptions))
    .pipe(assets = $.useref.assets())
    .pipe($.rev())
    .pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.ngAnnotate())
    .pipe($.uglify({ preserveComments: $.uglifySaveLicense })).on('error', conf.errorHandler('Uglify'))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('maps'))
    .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
    .pipe(cssFilter)
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.replace('../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/', '../fonts/'))
    .pipe($.minifyCss({ processImport: false }))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('maps'))
    .pipe(cssFilter.restore)
    .pipe(assets.restore())
    .pipe($.useref())
    .pipe($.revReplace())
    .pipe(htmlFilter)
    .pipe($.minifyHtml({
      empty: true,
      spare: true,
      quotes: true,
      conditionals: true
    }))
    .pipe(htmlFilter.restore)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/')))
    .pipe($.size({ title: path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/'), showFiles: true }));
  });

// Only applies for fonts from bower dependencies
// Custom fonts are handled by the "other" task
gulp.task('fonts', function () {
  return gulp.src($.mainBowerFiles())
    .pipe($.filter('**/*.{eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}'))
    .pipe($.flatten())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/fonts/')));
});

gulp.task('other', function () {
  var fileFilter = $.filter(function (file) {
    return file.stat.isFile();
  });

  return gulp.src([
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/**/*'),
    path.join('!' + conf.paths.src, '/**/*.{html,css,js,scss}')
  ])
    .pipe(fileFilter)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/')));
});

gulp.task('clean', function () {
  return $.del([path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/'), path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/')]);
});

gulp.task('build', ['html', 'fonts', 'other']);
```

Comment: have you tried removing tasks one by one to determine the cause?

Comment: Yes, although it's a little tricky since some of the tasks depend on other ones. I'll continue to try that and maybe it will reveal the answer.

Comment: it's just that you setup is very messy it will take a lot of time for someone to reproduce your problem. at least try to remove non-important bits

Comment: It came from a generator. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was this line:

```
.pipe($.rev())
```